# What data type do I use to load scientific (e) notation in SQL? Will eventually load into oracle DB with sqlloader

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, sql-loader

[image: What the data looks like]

What data type do I classify these numbers as?

I've tried number, float, float external, and binary double. All of these have given me an invalid datatype error when trying to create a table on SQL to eventually load into.

Comment: Please show table definition and how being loaded.

Comment: Numbers are numbers. They are independent of their representation. If you store the number 100, it can be shown as 100 or as 1e+02, but the number is the same. You should have no problem importing the numbers, if indeed they are numbers. Or are they actually not numbers, but STRINGS, meant to represent numbers in scientific notation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is currently in string format (and not in number format - if in fact your data is in number format, please see my comment to your question), then you don't need a data type - you need the proper format model to convert strings representing numbers in scientific format into actual numbers.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABFJEAA

For example:

```
SQL> select to_number('1.0e+02', '9.9eeee') as converted_to_number from dual;

CONVERTED_TO_NUMBER
-------------------
                100

1 row selected.
```

This takes the string `'1.0e+02'` (representing the number 100 in scientific notation) and uses the format model `'9.9eeee'` - see the linked documentation for this format model.

Comment: How/where would I put this statement in my control file? I have 28 columns all loading info in scientific notation which needs to be converted to number format.

Comment: load data
infile
HIGGS.csv
into table higgs
fields terminated by ","
(
CLASS NUMBER, 
LEPTON_PT NUMBER, 
LEPTON_ETA NUMBER,
LEPTON_PHI NUMBER, 
MISSING_ENERGY_MAG NUMBER, 
MISSING_ENERGY_PHI NUMBER, 
JET_1_PT NUMBER, 
JET_1_ETA NUMBER, 
JET_1_PHI NUMBER, 
JET_1_B-TAG NUMBER, 
JET_2_PT NUMBER, 
JET_2_ETA NUMBER, 
JET_2_PHI NUMBER,
JET_2_B-TAG NUMBER, 
JET_3_PT NUMBER, 
JET_3_ETA NUMBER,
JET_3_PHI NUMBER,
JET_3_B-TAG NUMBER,
JET_4_PT NUMBER, 
JET_4_ETA NUMBER,
JET_4_PHI NUMBER,
JET_4_B-TAG NUMBER,
)